# php fopen - how can I use fopen to open just a part of the file,

Tags: php, calendar, fopen, icalendar

Lets admit we have a huge text file, more exact a ics file. Huge... 10MB or more
And we want to read out only a piece of it with php
 
from

```
'BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20111130T144848Z' 
...
```

to the next occurrence of

```
...
 'END:VEVENT'.
```

In order to use it as a array
Someone has a hint ?

Comment: use fseek to navigate: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php and fread to read data: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

Comment: `fopen()` just opens the file, it doesn't read any of it. Just stop calling `fgets()` when you reach the end line.

Comment: I would suggest caching the part you need once every X minutes, this way the load is reduced. Especially when you don't know where this part is located, the worst case results in searching through 10 MB of data and no finding it at all. 
So if you have to do that every request it will take alot of time.

Comment: what do you mean by `out only a piece` a since `VCALENDAR` can contain multiple `VEVENT` .. are you looking at the first one ? or last one .. or random

Comment: good question, the last one. CREATED contains a time stamp that should be after VEVENT unique. Else take the last. .... (2 minutes later) OK, I checked it. the timestamps are unique.

Comment: Also take a look at : https://github.com/fruux/sabre-vobject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
$numb=0;
$result=array();
$handle = @fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
$exit=0;
  while (($buffer = fgets($handle) && $exit==0) {
        if(strpos($buffer,'BEGIN:VEVENT')){
          $onoff=1;
        }
        if ($onoff==1){
          $result[$numb]=$buffer;
          $numb=numb+1;
        }
        if(strpos($buffer,'END:VEVENT')){
          $onoff=0;
          $exit=1;
         }

    }
  if (!feof($handle)) {
      echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
  }
  fclose($handle);
 }
```

Comment: if you have to handle multiple istances in the same file you can just add a new if to set the 'exit' parameter as you like :)